# How to allow pick mark inside certain area?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have 4 latlong points and I want to allow user to pick marker only inside these latlngs. these are the 4 points:

```
"new_latitude1": 24.790874, "new_longitude1": 46.860488
"new_latitude2": 24.828583, "new_longitude2": 46.842389
"new_latitude3": 24.856611, "new_longitude3": 46.86747
"new_latitude4": 24.837425, "new_longitude4": 46.895313
```

Comment: you can draw radius by specifying center on MAP, and can restrict to select coordinates with in the radius. i.e 1 mile radius.

Comment: Use the PolyUtil class - define a polygon (List<LatLng> with your points above) and use 'containsLocation' with the "picked" marker location.  Utility assumes closed polygon so adding 5th point as first is optional.  The geodesic option lets you decide if you want the "box" to conform to the earth's surface or a simple tangential plane.